Can’t boot into macOS or Windows but grub works fine. How to combine two EFI partitions?
I have an early 2015 MacBookPro and my goal is to boot into macOS, Windows, and grub (to choose between Linux distros)
I had macOS and grub working just fine for over a year and when I installed Windows today, the whole house came folding down.  Now I can’t boot into macOS or Windows and verified the partitions are clearly still there (see below). Thankfully, I can still boot into all my Linux distros thru grub! Though I’ve created a bit of a hall of mirrors because of OpenCore, rEFInd, and having 2 EFI partitions (yikes!).
When I installed elementaryOS 7.1 earlier this year, it had a requirement that my EFI partition was at least 550MB.  I couldn’t resize the original 200MB EFI created by macOS so I just created a new EFI to make the installer happy. I know this is when the mess started and I would like to learn how to:

combine my EFI partitions so I can delete my 200MB EFI partition
clean up my boot entries (see below) (ie. how do I verify which entries are valid?)
create a simple way to choose between all my installs (happy to delete OpenCore and reEFInd for better alternatives)

I’m currently in the process of installing Windows to an external - if keeping Windows on my internal proves to be too troublesome, I’m willing to revert to just macOS and Linux internally.
Partition Info
root@Ecstatic:~# gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 490234752 sectors, 233.8 GiB
Model: APPLE SSD SM0256
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 408F0543-A797-4F05-BBD6-B50610AB79EA
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 490234718
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4518 sectors (2.2 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          411648       137130391   65.2 GiB    FFFF  macOS Monterey
   3       137132032       234786815   46.6 GiB    0700  Windows 10
   4       234786816       235913215   550.0 MiB   0700  larger EFI for eOS ...
   5       235913216       279894014   21.0 GiB    8300  elementary OS 7.1
   6       279894016       313657343   16.1 GiB    8300  /home
   7       313657344       326242303   6.0 GiB     0700  Batocera
   8       326242304       406347775   38.2 GiB    8300  /userdata & /DATA
   9       406347776       490233855   40.0 GiB    8300  CasaOS

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-9): 2
Partition GUID code: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF (Unknown)
Partition unique GUID: 0D132205-5E33-4588-8A69-C80702D4F1EF
First sector: 411648 (at 201.0 MiB)
Last sector: 137130391 (at 65.4 GiB)
Partition size: 136718744 sectors (65.2 GiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'macOS Monterey'

Boot Entries
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0015,0014,0001,0013,0080,000B,0002
Boot0001* OpenCore      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,c8fb5fc8-a5af-4134-a706-831717b817d8,0x28,0x64000)/File(EFI\OC\OpenCore.efi)
Boot0002* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,c8fb5fc8-a5af-4134-a706-831717b817d8,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000B* elementary OS 7.1 Horus       HD(1,GPT,05805631-8027-4ae2-9eab-fd898f4561ef,0x28,0x2007d8)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0013* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,c8fb5fc8-a5af-4134-a706-831717b817d8,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....I...............
Boot0014* ubuntu        HD(4,GPT,943e1413-c9cb-4df9-b4f1-78b9021ec2e1,0xdfe9000,0x113000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0015* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(4,GPT,943e1413-c9cb-4df9-b4f1-78b9021ec2e1,0xdfe9000,0x113000)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0080* Mac OS X      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,0d132205-5e33-4588-8a69-c80702d4f1ef,0x64800,0xdf84758)/VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,59f3501d4208f74095633d16ef09f998)/File(\9012ED6D-D6A4-3B49-AED3-FA9FAEEA3E00\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)
Boot0081* Mac OS X      VenMedia(be74fcf7-0b7c-49f3-9147-01f4042e6842,1698aa01f65ab94cb051438f1123db8e)/File(\01EF3644-034C-4AC9-B6CD-07E9E978C835\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)


You don't; You modify Grub to point to the EFI partition for Windows and the EFI for Linux based on the boot menu option that is selected. You would have to reinstall all the operating systems if you wanted a single EFI partition.

The code shown from gdisk for the macOS partition is FFFF, which stands for unknown. It would be helpful to use the i command from gdisk to get the actual partition GUID code for this partition. Edit your answer and add the gdisk output. I would expect the value to be FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF, but I want to confirm this.

You might get assistance from Ask Different with answers like this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310342/triple-booting-mac-windows-and-linux-a-boot-load-nightmare from @DavidAnderson

@DavidAnderson I updated my answer to the output of “i”

@Gilby took a quick look at the answer you linked and will see if I can use some of the commands stated to restore my mac to point back to rEFInd as you are correct, the answer does parallel my situation (outside of Bootcamp)

@Gilby turns out I can get into rEFInd, it just won’t boot the Windows or macOS entries. Ideally I just wish to restore seeing macOS, Windows, and GRUB2 in Apple’s bootloader - I have this working just fine on an external NVMe for a different system.

You need to use gdisk to change code for partition 2 from FFFF to AF0A.

@DavidAnderson thank you for reminding me this happens!  I’m back in macOS! #yeay  How do I restore booting into Windows?  I tried to reinstall refind and it won’t come up, I tried blessing refind_x64.efi, it succeeds but doesn’t come up on boot. I’m under the assumption rEFInd is the easiest way to boot into my Windows partition.  I happen to have OpenCore installed but nothing happens if I select the Windows partition.

just an update on this front: as I see recommended in a lot of answers and posts - the way out is to start clean & set things up the right way from the get go. I just nuked Windows, macOS, and 2 Linux distros leaving Ubuntu Server behind. I may revisit this project but for now, it’s an x86 build & dev server. Thanks again everyone for all your help!
